# Explode with regexp

Tags: php, regex

i have a string like `{ASK(Value, Value, 'Sentence', Some_Char)}` and i need to get of exploded values in `()`. What i am doing wrong?

```
preg_match_all('/\{ASK\((.*?),\)\}/', '{ASK(Value, Value, \'Sentence\', X)}', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: well, nothing in `{ASK(Value, Value, 'Sentence', Some_Char)}` ends with `,)}`, so you match nothing

Comment: What is the format of the string? One example doesn't cut it. I can write a regex that works for this example, but may fail some time in the future.

Comment: @JanDvorak as i understood `(.*?),` should search each time until `,` or i am wrong?

Comment: @Kirix `(.*?)` matches as little as possible such the rest can match as well. In your case, `,` can match after `Value`, but `)}` doesn't match at that position, and `,` doesn't match where `)}` is.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the comma from your regular expression, and it matches.

```
preg_match_all('/\{ASK\((.*?)\)\}/', '{ASK(Value, Value, \'Sentence\', X)}', $matches);
print_r($matches);

//Explode the matched group
$exploded = explode(',',$matches[1]); 
print_r($exploded);

/*
 * Note that we used $matches[1] instead of $matches[0], 
 * since the first element contains the entire matched 
 * expression, and each subsequent element contains the matching groups.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "{ASK(Value, Value, 'Sentence', Some_Char)}";
$p = '#\{ASK\((.*?)\)\}#';
preg_match_all($p, $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply split & explode

```
$Myval = "{ASK(Value, Value, 'Sentence', Some_Char)}";

$splitedVal = split('[()]', $Myval);

$explodedVal = explode(",", $splitedVal[1]);

print_r($explodedVal);
```

// output

```
Array ( [0] => Value [1] => Value [2] => 'Sentence' [3] => Some_Char )
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this (though not entirely contained within the regex) might be:

```
preg_match_all('/\{ASK\([^)]*\)\}/', '{ASK(Value, Value, \'Sentence\', X)}', $matches);
$values = explode($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as your `Values`, `Sentences`, and `Chars` do not contain `,` or `)`, then this single regex pattern will deliver without the extra `explode()` call.

Pattern: `~(?:\G, |ASK\()\K[^,)]+~`  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PorzXY/1))

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8bb759cab851526a8e982986e049d6a07fcdf72e))

```
$string="{ASK(Value, Value, 'Sentence', Some_Char)}";

print_r(preg_match_all('~(?:\G, |ASK\()\K[^,)]+~',$string,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Value
    [1] => Value
    [2] => 'Sentence'
    [3] => Some_Char
)
```

The "magic" is in the `\G`.  This tells regex to continue matching at the start of the string or just after the previous match.  Here is a similar answer that I've posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373347/2943403