# How to individually match all numbers that immediately follow a keyword?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this string:

```
28.6MH\/s 27.3MH\/s | Temp(C): 64 66 61 64 63 | Fan: 74% 76% 69% 75% 72% | HW: 21 21 21
```

and I want to extract the `Temp` values, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The expression that I came up with (and doesn't work) is:

```
((?<temp>\d\d)(?!\.).+(?!Fan))+
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1PTdaOP448fV_Yk-)

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/69jncg/1)?

Comment: Thanks! It does work but I still don't understand how. I use it anyway even if I had to modify the rest of the code to read the first group of matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern: `/(?:\G(?!^)|Temp\(C\):) \K\d+/` ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ixc1Ia/1))

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70b0e447994ac8cb1a73d9f7c8f4b61359518d82))

```
$in='28.6MH\/s 27.3MH\/s | Temp(C): 64 66 61 64 63 | Fan: 74% 76% 69% 75% 72% | HW: 21 21 21 ';

var_export(preg_match_all('/(?:\G(?!^)|Temp\(C\):) \K\d+/',$in,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '64',
  1 => '66',
  2 => '61',
  3 => '64',
  4 => '63',
)
```

Explanation:

You can see the official terminology explanation in the Pattern Demo link, but here is my way of explaining...

```
(?:         # start a non-capturing group so that regex understands the piped "alternatives"
\G          # match from the start of the string or where the previous match left off
(?!^)       # ...but not at the start of the string (for your case, this can actually be omitted, but it is a more trustworthy pattern with it included
|           # OR
Temp\(C\):  # literally match Temp(C):
)           # end the non-capturing group
            # <-- there is a blank space there which needs to be matched
\K          # "release" previous matched characters (restart fullstring match)
\d+         # match one or more digits greedily
```

The pattern stops when it hits that `|` ("space and pipe") after `63` because they  aren't matched by `\d+` ("space and digits").

Comment: By far the best solution to my problem and a very comprehensive answer. Thanks!

Comment: @mickmacusa I voted your answer but I'm told that my vote is not displayed because I don't have at least 15 points reputation... Is there any other way to go?

Answer (score 1):

With `preg_match()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
$str = "28.6MH\/s 27.3MH\/s | Temp(C): 64 66 61 64 63 | Fan: 74% 76% 69% 75% 72% | HW: 21 21 21";
preg_match('/(?<=Temp\(C\): )[\s\d]+(?=\| Fan)/', $str, $m);
$temp_values = $m[0];

print_r($temp_values);
```

The output:

```
64 66 61 64 63
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't return an array of values. Useful anyway if you explode the string after. Thanks!